# Chossing between gradient boosting algorithms

Tags: classification, methodology, gradient-boosting-decision-trees

I just stepped in machine learning competitions and it looks like most of the mid-sized dataset competitions are won by Gradient boosting based models. However I came accross case where [LightGBM](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/),[Catboost](https://catboost.ai/) or [Adaboost](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier.html) had very different scores.

Is there a method to choose between those algorithms?

Answer (score 1):

I would say `Catboost` and `lightgbm` perform similarly and its purely a matter of choice.
Some of my colleagues prefered `Catboost` when dataset has lots of categorical columns, but I rarely saw any advantage over `lightgbm`.

there is a great article comparing `CatBoost vs. Light GBM vs. XGBoost`
https://towardsdatascience.com/catboost-vs-light-gbm-vs-xgboost-5f93620723db

And another article comparing even more boosting algos
https://medium.com/@divyagera2402/boosting-algorithms-adaboost-gradient-boosting-xgb-light-gbm-and-catboost-e7d2dbc4e4ca